# H2 column name select returning incorrect column name; "Column "OUT_ID" not found; SQL statement:"

Tags: sql, import, h2, csv

I am using the [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), version "H2 1.3.170 (2012-11-30)"

I have the following **tab** delimited file contents:

```
in:value1:String    out:id:Int  out:description:String
N/A 0   N/A
Forced Available    1   Forced Available
Forced Not Available    2   Forced Not Available
```

I am using the following statement to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE xo_coverage_voip_on_xo_override AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('C:\Temp\xo_coverage_voip_on_xo_override.tab', 'in_value_1' || chr(9) || 'out_id' || chr(9) || 'out_description', 'UTF-8', chr(9));
```

I attempt to use the created table with this:

```
SELECT out_id FROM xo_coverage_voip_on_xo_override;
```

And I receive this error:

```
"Column "OUT_ID" not found; SQL statement:"
```

Where am I going wrong?

Additionally, I would really like to remove the first row from the table before it is inserted. However, I wasn't able to get a WHERE clause to work.

Any assistance you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you try `select "out:id:Int" from xo_coverage_voip_on_xo_override`?

Comment: Or, as an alternative, use `create table xo_coverage_voip_on_xo_override(in_value1 varchar, out_id int, out_description varchar) as select * from csvread(...)` and then the query you used?

Comment: @Thomas Mueller: When trying "SELECT out:id:Int FROM XO_COVERAGE_VOIP_ON_XO_OVERRIDE;", I got this error: "Column "OUT" not found; SQL statement:"

Comment: @Thomas Mueller: When trying "CREATE TABLE xo_coverage_voip_on_xo_override1(in_value1 varchar, out_id int, out_description varchar) AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('C:\Temp\xo_coverage_voip_on_xo_override.tab', 'in_value_1' || chr(9) || 'out_id' || chr(9) || 'out_description', 'UTF-8', chr(9));", I got this error: "Data conversion error converting "'out:id:Int' (XO_COVERAGE_VOIP_ON_XO_OVERRIDE1: OUT_ID INT)"; SQL statement:
 -- row #2 ('in:value1:String', 'out:id:Int', 'out:description:String') [22018-170] 22018/22018"

Comment: The error makes sense as the "header row" won't pass the int conversion.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution ends up being this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE xo_coverage_voip_on_xo_override1(in_value1 varchar, out_id int, out_description varchar)
  AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('C:\Temp\xo_coverage_voip_on_xo_override.tab', null, 'UTF-8', chr(9));
```

The key is to have the CSVREAD query load data into a fully specified table. And to provide "null" for the header row so it is skipped in the file.